# how can get high performance when foreach DataRow in a DataTable in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, datatable

I get a datatable (**ora_dt**) from an Oracle DB, now i need to add an column(**colu_sql**) in **ora_dt**,however i have to get **colu_sql**'s value from some Sqlserver DBs.

Here is my code:

```
public void ProcessDataTable(DataSet _ds)
{
    _ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descpition", typeof(string)));

    int countryId = -1;
    string des_ID = string.Empty;
    string geo = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow row in _ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (row["des_ID"] != DBNull.Value)
            des_ID = row["des_ID"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(des_ID))
        {
            if (countryId == 12 || countryId == 13)
                geo = "NA";
            else if ((countryId == 10 || countryId == 11))
                geo = "LA";
            else
                geo = "EMEA";
            row["Descpition"] = GetDes(geo, des_ID);
        }
        else { row["ExemptionDes"] = string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

For every DataRow, inorder to get row["Descpition"] value, i have to check its **geo** and **des_id**, and select them from another SqlserverDB.

If the row counts in DataTable is very large, then when i foreach the DataTable, i have to visit the sqlserver db many times, it makes performance bad,

Actually i cannot add new column description in Oracle.how can get high performance when foreach DataRow in a DataTable in my code?

`private string GetDes(string geo, string des_ID)
{
    string description = string.Empty;
    string query = "select description from geo_exemption  where des_ID= " + des_ID;
    Database DbSQL = DbSQLFactory.CreateDatabase(geo);
    using (DataReader dr = DbSQL.ExecuteReader(sqlCmd))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["description"] != null)
                description = dr["description"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    return description;
}`

Comment: Why do you not start by not doing a string lookup every time yu hit the row. dr["description"] is a LOT slower than dr[0] and as you control the SQL you should know the ordinal - or you can ask the datareader for the ordinal and keep it in a variable. THis is a lot of difference in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be getting all the records for `description` and `des_ID` from `geo_exemption` in a single datatable at one go and then using LINQ to filter out the records based on des_ID. In this way you would need to hit the database only once. Rest all the operations will happen on asp.net side.

**EDIT:**

```
public void ProcessDataTable(DataSet _ds)
{
    if (Session["GeoExpAllRec"] == null)
    {
        //Fetch all records here and add it to a datatable i.e. "select des_ID, description from geo_exemption"
        //Then Add the datatable to the session variable Session["GeoExpAllRec"]
    }

    _ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descpition", typeof(string)));

    int countryId = -1;
    string des_ID = string.Empty;
    string geo = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow row in _ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (row["des_ID"] != DBNull.Value)
            des_ID = row["des_ID"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(des_ID))
        {
            if (countryId == 12 || countryId == 13)
                geo = "NA";
            else if ((countryId == 10 || countryId == 11))
                geo = "LA";
            else
                geo = "EMEA";

            //Instead of calling "GetDes" function which will hit the database
            //Type-cast the session variable Session["GeoExpAllRec"] to datatable i.e. (Session["GeoExpAllRec"] as DataTable)
            //Fire a LINQ query on the datatable to get the desired Description like below

            //row["Descpition"] = GetDes(geo, des_ID);

            DataTable dt = (Session["GeoExpAllRec"] as DataTable);
            row["Descpition"] = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("des_ID") == des_ID).First()["description"];

        }
        else { row["ExemptionDes"] = string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx， however i have no idea to get all the records from geo_exemption.  there is not only one sqlserver db.  different geo leads different sql db. i have to check geo in _ds.Tables[0].Rows, and get sql db by using geo.  this issue make me have to choose the above bad solution.

Comment: Wouldn't just removing the where clause from the query which is querying geo_exemption would fetch all the records? You can fire this query on page load or at the start of ProcessDataTable function and put it in a session variable and then put this code across a null check for the session variable. Add where you are hitting the database just type cast the session variable to datatable and fire a linq query. I have updated my answer to accommodate this.

Comment: I think，not only des_ID also need geo to get records.  e.g.first i need to get which sql db i should use。 e.g：  geo="NA", Database NA = DbSQLFactory.CreateDatabase(geo),then  get records from NA.  Actually there are three sql db on server has same table structure, like NADB,EMEADB,LADB.  If i get all the Hundreds of thousands records from these three DBs, I think it will take worse performance.